# How to stop dio get when the internet is off?

Tags: flutter, dio

the request is just waiting and not resulting an error, i want an error to be produced when there is no internet but it's just waiting forever

i tried

sendTimeout: 600000,

receiveTimeout: 600000,

but same result

[vscode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5DIv.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [Read and abide by this please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: Also this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your logic inside try/catch block.

```
try {
  var response = await _dio.getUri(
    Uri.parse(uri));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return response.data;
  } else {
    throw response;
  }
} on SocketException catch (e) {
  throw SocketException(e.toString());
} on FormatException catch (_) {
  throw FormatException("Unable to process the data");
} catch (e) {
  throw e;
}
```